# What is this (tropical?) plant called?

Tags: identification, leaves, tropical

Does anyone know what this plant is called?

[image]

It looks tropical-ish to me, but I don't know.  Some bromeliad, maybe?

I don't have access to the plant shown in the picture, BTW.  I found the picture online, without any other identification info.

---

EDIT

I found some candidates by scanning results from Google Image Search.

Interestingly enough, none is a bromeliad, or even tropical.  In order of similarity (to my eyes) to the picture above:

1. *Veratrum californicum* (aka California corn lilies) 
   http://media.gettyimages.com/photos/false-hellebore-pattern-veratrum-californicum-picture-id131409908
2. *Veratrum viride* (aka false hellebore)
    [image]
3. *Allium tricoccum* (aka [wild] leeks)
   [image]

---

After some more scanning, I'm inclined to call it some species of *Veratrum*/corn lily: a local beauty with an exotic look.

Comment: Not any bromeliad I know of

Comment: If it is Allium, you should try to smell cut leaves

Comment: It's definitely not a bromeliad. Yes allium plants will have an distinguished onion scent to them. I think veratrum is your closest guess.

Comment: @OhmWang: as I wrote in my original message: *I don't have access to the plant.*

Answer (score 3):

Nice search, it could be also a variety of Dracaena's family

[image]

There is also a plant very similar to Veratrum, Gentiana Maggiore.
[image]

Comment: Close on the colour and shape but dracaena do not have the raised ribs in the leaves the first photo seems to show.